# Managing JAR dependencies in a solo development environment

Tags: java, jar, maven

Should I use something like maven for this? Or would finding them as they occur be better? I am not supporting any users other than myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Maven for solo and team projects.  The setup is minimal and I've found it much easier even in solo projects..  sometimes you can spend a fair bit of time tracking down depenencies for some project of interest... why bother when Maven will do it for you *and* help keep you from getting conflicts between project dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

As always, it depends. I have found maven to work nicely when using popular libraries that are available in major maven repositories, so that I didn't have to configure much myself. Also, some fancy IDEs like Netbeans make jar management with maven a real pleasure: just start typing a name of a jar or even a class in that jar and the libraries are magically found and added as a dependency to your project.

Without an IDE it is probably much more hassle to add dependencies by hand, but that my still be worth it. In the end, what other choices have you got. Ant?

Comment: Ant has Ivy which gives the module dependency management requested by the poster.

Answer (score 0):

Well, without more details I would simply say: don't you find that Maven makes things easier (this is very likely where the answer to your question resides)? If you don't then don't use it. If you do, then you have your answer. Personally, I use it for all my projects (professional, personal, big teams, small teams, even teams of one).